# Unable to switch from 2nd activity to the first activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying out a simple application that has two screen(or activity).I used intent to switch to another activity when i click a button.This works fine, but from the second activity when i try to switch back to the previous screen(or activity), then i get error as unforunantely SimpleIntent has stopped. 
SimpleIntent is the name of my project.

Why can't i swtich back to the previous screen?

Here is my AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.SimpleIntent"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Screen"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.SimpleIntent.SCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I don't where is logCat in Intellij(I am a beginner), but i think it should be this : [link] (http://pastebin.com/bpys7Wa0)

Answer (score 1):

Call Finish to end the activity and go back
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

> **public void finish ()**
>
> *Added in API level 1
> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated >back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().*

Also read here:

> http://d.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

That was not your logcat, that was your console, logcat should be another tab/window.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugging-with-logcat.html

Answer (score 1):

just override the following method in the MyActivity

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

Start Activity on your onClick method using

```
  startActivityForResult(intentName, 0);
```

In Screen Activity you use/override onStop() method

```
  @Override
  protected void onStop()
  {
      super.onStop();
  }
```

Comment: yes as i mentioned, i tried your solution and it works perfectly, but i want to use intent to switch to the previous activity, in the same way as i used in MyActivity Activity to Switch to Screen Activity

Comment: Ok thanks it works now, but i wanted to know isn't there a simple method to switch to previous screen, why does my original method don't work to switch from Screen to Activity when i perfectly switch to Scrren from MyActivity using the same method.